# What does "with transfer" mean in the context of guided tours?

Tags: transportation, tours

On many tour sites such as grayline, goldentours, evanevanstours, etc. tours are either listed as "with transfer" or have an upgrade option for "transfer." Nothing on any of the sites seems to explain what the "transfer" aspect is and why you would want that over and above the basic guided tour.

Can anyone tell me what this is and under what conditions it would be better to purchase the tour with it?

Comment: Can mean different things but basically connecting you from the tour proper to some other service. Example picking you from the airport, dropping you off to the airport afterwards are all considered transfer. The beauty of having a transfer by the tour operator is that you essentially cannot miss the start of the tour e,g. you could lose your way getting to the tour start point because you were coming by yourself while if it is a transfer, the tour company could conceivably delay departure for you because they are the ones bringing you from your hotel or airport etc.

Comment: Also, even when the tour/travel package is not guided, that transfers are an option, getting you to and from transit stations (airport/train/bus) to accommodations etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

99% of the time, "transfer" means they will pick you up and take you to the airport on arrival/departure.  Or seaport or train station if that's more appropriate.

Typically, the guided part of these tours start the morning after you first night in the origin city.  The transfer are just a bus/car ride to/from the hotel.

When you select the transfer option, you will get an additional guide specifying where to meet the transfer vehicle/operator on arrival.